# Delete sender in separate slot

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, signals-slots

I have an object that emits 3 different signals, and I would like to transfer these signals as well as delete the sender of them. This object is located in another object that will act as the emitter of these signals.

Usally I would to it like this:

```
void SomeClass::someSideFunction() {
    Request* request = _StorageProvider.insert("somedata");

    connect(request, SIGNAL(succeded()),        this, SLOT(handleSucceded()));
    connect(request, SIGNAL(failed()),          this, SLOT(handleFailed()));
    connect(request, SIGNAL(alreadyExists()),   this, SLOT(handleAlreadyExists()));
}

void SomeClass::handleSucceded() {
    Request* request = qobject_cast<Request*>(sender());
    if(request != NULL) request ->deleteLater();
    emit succeded();
}

void SomeClass::handleFailed() {
    Request* request = qobject_cast<Request*>(sender());
    if(request != NULL) request ->deleteLater();
    emit failed();
}

void SomeClass::handleAlreadyExists() {
    Request* request = qobject_cast<Request*>(sender());
    if(request != NULL) request ->deleteLater();
    emit alreadyExists();
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Even though the "request" is a child of the storageProvider, there are way to many requests going on for me to just wait to delete them until the parent dies.

I was thinking some kind of solution like this:

```
connect(request, SIGNAL(succeded()),        this, SIGNAL(succeded()));
connect(request, SIGNAL(failed()),          this, SIGNAL(failed()));
connect(request, SIGNAL(alreadyExists()),   this, SIGNAL(alreadyExists()));
connect(request, SIGNAL(succeded()),        this, SLOT(memoryHnadler()));
connect(request, SIGNAL(failed()),          this, SLOT(memoryHnadler()));
connect(request, SIGNAL(alreadyExists()),   this, SLOT(memoryHnadler()));
```

Where the memory handler would delete the sender if it exists. What would be the downside of this approach and what might be a better one?

Notice that the object will only emit one of these signals when it is done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see any downside to your second approach. Qt will first send the signals and later the memory handler, as it executes in the same order as you declare the connections.

The memory handler must be the only one deleting the Request object.

Another approach will be to emit the signals with the Request object as an argument, and then rely to the user slot to delete them. But if no user slot is declared, you will keep memory growing...

Comment: You can't delete the sender object in the receiver slot - in most cases, control flows back to the sender - if you've deleted it, you're  in undefined behavior territory. (Unless you use deleteLater - but then the first approach is shorter and requires less slots.)

Comment: Yes, of course, never call delete from a slot if you're trying to delete the caller, always deleteLater.

Comment: will the fact that these objects are a child to something affect anything? i will be able to delete them here and when the parents kills its kids, it wont find this one right?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Look at the documentation: "__You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents. For example, when the user removes a toolbar it may lead to the application deleting one of its QToolBar objects, in which case the tool bar's QMainWindow parent would detect the change and reconfigure its screen space accordingly.__" (from http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/objecttrees.html)

Answer (score 3):

An option is to have the request schedule its own deletion using QObject::deleteLater(). Like this:

```
void Request::emitSucceeded() {
    emit succeeded();
    deleteLater();
}

void Request::emitFailed(int errorCode, const QString& errorString ) {
    m_errorCode = errorCode;
    m_errorString = errorString;
    emit failed();
    deleteLater();
}
```

For instance, KDELib's base class for asynchronous operations, [KJob](http://api.kde.org/4.8-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKJob.html), is using this pattern (unless explicitly disabled via setAutoDelete(false)).